# C# Prime Number Generator Out of Memory

Tags: c#, numbers, generator, out-of-memory

```
 public class Atkin_Algo : IEnumerable<ulong>
 {
      private List<ulong> primes;
      private ulong limit;

      public Atkin_Algo(ulong _limit)
      {
           limit = _limit;
           primes = new List<ulong>();
      }

      public IEnumerator<ulong> GetEnumerator()
      {
           if (!primes.Any())
                Find_Primes();

           foreach (var p in primes)
                yield return p;
      }

      IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
      {
           return GetEnumerator();
      }

      private void Find_Primes()
      {
           var is_prime = new bool[limit + 1];
           var sqrt = Math.Sqrt(limit);

           for (ulong x = 1; x <= sqrt; x++)
           {
                for (ulong y = 1; y <= sqrt; y++)
                {
                     var n = 4 * x * x + y * y;
                     if (n <= limit && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5))
                     {
                          is_prime[n] ^= true;
                     }

                     n = 3 * x * x + y * y;
                     if (n <= limit && n % 12 == 7)
                     {
                          is_prime[n] ^= true;
                     }

                     n = 3 * x * x - y * y;
                     if (x > y && n <= limit && n % 12 == 11)
                     {
                          is_prime[n] ^= true;
                     }
                }
           }

           for (ulong n = 5; n <= sqrt; n++)
           {
                if (is_prime[n])
                {
                     var s = n * n;
                     for (ulong k = s; k <= limit; k += s)
                     {
                          is_prime[k] = false;
                     }
                }
           }

           primes.Add(2);

           primes.Add(3);

           for (ulong n = 5; n <= limit; n += 2)
           {
                if (is_prime[n])
                {
                     primes.Add(n);
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

So my problem is when I want to generate a LARGE list I get OutOfMemoryException which is to be expected, but I want to be able to work around this. I have not done anything like this before any advice would greatly be appreciated.

The reason why I want to avoid this problem is to soon make use of the BigInteger class and be able to generate LARGE prime numbers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the limit till which you want to find primes.

Comment: I wouldn't use Atkins if it wasn't for an actually limited amount of numbers, but you don't really, really limit yourself. It's just an extra parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key limitation is the large array of bools that you have to keep around. You're probably running against the limit to the size of an array; instead of a proper array, try using multiple arrays. You can write functions to make it as easy to use as an array, but behind the scenes it's backed by multiple arrays (perhaps one for numbers from 0-1 million, another for 1mio-2mio, and so on).

Then when those arrays get really too big for memory, you can save them to disk and load, one at a time, the one you need (obviously this will get much slower than in-memory access. Luckily, many accesses should be to the same array as last time, so if you keep it around that'll help).

You are also causing trouble for yourself by keeping the result primes all in a big list in memory. You're better off writing them to disk (and perhaps on the screen) as you find them, and then not keeping them in memory.

Comment: The bool array is hungry but it's the list of unsigned longs at the end that pushes it over the edge.

Comment: yeah what is the point in housing them in memory. save em out and move on

Comment: Totally agreed. The reason I talk about the sieve array first is that you can't get rid of that one, you have to keep it.

Comment: @Parker What would be the best way to dump this list into a text file as values are found? Could you post an example please?

Comment: @DrewPierce What would be the best way to dump this list into a text file as values are found? Could you post an example please?

Comment: @IdahoSixString .... funny you should ask....   http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/

Comment: @DrewPierce I am wanting to use my algorithm to generate primes that are much greater than the range of 50 million and currently I can already generate a list up to 100 million.

Comment: @IdahoSixString .....   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx